# How do I refresh a page if a field width changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to edit a page on Knack that allows JS modifications in combination with CSS formatting.  The change I made was to lock the header on each page that uses an excel format.  This seems to break when the user changes the number of rows in a drop down selection or navigates to the next page.

I'm sure there are a few ways to do this but I thought the easiest way to manage this would be to look at the first row's style and refresh the page if the minimum width is less than the desired length.  Something like if the first entry in the header is not XXX amount of pixels, reload page using window.location.reload(); or similar.

Here is an example of the JS:

```
$( document ).on ('knack-page-render.any', (function(event, view, data) {
  var $table = $('#view_60 > table');
  var $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children();
  var newWidths = [];
  var colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function(index, val) {
    /* Debug message*/
    //console.log("Index: " + index + ". Value=" + $(this).width());
      return $(this).width();
    }).get();
  var $headerCells =  $table.find('thead tr').children();  
  //Evaluate new max width
  $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i){ 
    var headerWidth = $(this).width();    
    var bodyRowWidth = colWidth[i];
    var newWidth = headerWidth;
    if (bodyRowWidth > newWidth){
        newWidth = bodyRowWidth;           
    }
     newWidth++;
    $(this).css("min-width", newWidth + "px");
    newWidths[i] = newWidth;
    /* Debug message*/
   // console.log("Cell: " + i + ", header width=", headerWidth + ", bodyRowWidth=" +  bodyRowWidth + ", idealWidth=" + newWidth + " Classes: " + $(this).attr('class'));    
  });
  // Set new widths everywhere
  $table.find('tbody tr:first').children().each(function(i){
    //console.log("Setting new width to " + newWidths[i]);
    $(this).css("min-width", ( newWidths[i]) + "px");
  });
}));
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
#view_52 table {border-collapse: collapse;} 
#view_52 thead {display:block; padding: 2px; margin: 0px;} 
#view_52 tbody {display:block; overflow:auto; width 100%; margin: 0px; height:500px; padding:2px;}
```

Comment: Please phrase a question. There is non in yours. Reduce your code to a smaler fraction of code if it's possible.

Comment: The question is the main subject really.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to look at the field width or style settings of a section of the webpage to queue a refresh command.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'knack-page-render.any' to 'knack-view-render.any'

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.